# PL/SQL Package Cursor with custom return value (like in the procedure)

Tags: oracle, plsql, package

Is it possible to define a cursor with custom return value (columns from different tables..) ?

For example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE pkg
IS
   CURSOR emp_cur (id_in IN employees.employee_id%TYPE)
      RETURN employees%ROWTYPE;
END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY pkg
IS
   CURSOR emp_cur (id_in IN employees.employee_id%TYPE)
      RETURN employees%ROWTYPE
   IS
      SELECT *
        FROM employees
       WHERE employee_id = id_in;
END;
/
```

This works because the employees is a single table.

In the procedure i can define cursor

CURSOR CUR_TEST ....
and the later
TYPE t_cur_test IS TABLE OF CUR_TEST %ROWTYPE INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
var_t_cur_test  t_cur_test ;

an it works.

In the package however with

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE TEST
IS
   -- Public types
      
            CURSOR CUR_TEST
        RETURN CUR_TEST%ROWTYPE;
```

i am getting -> 1/14     PLS-00304: cannot compile body of 'CUR_TEST' without its specification.

Is there any way to do this ?

Comment: Is your query dynamic? If not, then check this: [Explicit cursor **definition**](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/static-sql.html#GUID-3FD3219B-E28D-47D0-A447-812C758BCDFB). If yes, then check this: [Record Variables](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-collections-and-records.html#GUID-75875E26-FC7B-4513-A5E2-EDA26F1D67B1)

Comment: `cur_test` is invalid because there's no `cur_test%rowtype`. If you want to to return a specific row type then you will need to define one first.